# Multiple Biztalk host instances writing to single file

Tags: file, biztalk

We have four Biztalk servers on production envionment. The sendport is configured to write incoming message in one textfile. This port receives thousands of messages in a day. So multiple host instances tries to write to file at single time, before one instance finishes writing complete record another instances starts writing new record causing data scattered all over the file.

What can we do resolve this issue?

Comment: Two quick questions - 1. Why do you need to write to a single file? what is your business process? 2. If message A is written to disk and then message B is immediate written to disk (overwriting the contents of message A), is this acceptable?

Comment: These are invidual records. We put all records that we receive in a single day in single file. Messagge A is overwritten by Message B is not acceptable as that could cause data loss. Right now, before end of record of A happens, Message B starts writing. I saw many sites mentioning using Biztalk host clustering to prevent data duplication in case of FTP Adapters. But I am using File Adapter.

Answer (score 3):

> ...before one instance finishes writing complete record another instances starts writing new record causing data scattered all over the file.
>
> What can we do resolve this issue?

The easy way is to only use a single Host Instance to write data to the file, however you may then start to experience throttling issues. Alternatively, you could explore using the 'Allow Cache on write' option on the File Adapter which may offer some improvements.

However, I think your approach is wrong. You cannot expect four separate and totally disconnected processes (across 4 servers no-less) to reliably append to a single file - IN ORDER.

I therefore think you should look re-architecting this solution:

1. As each message is received, write the contents of the message to a database table (a simple INSERT) with an 'unprocessed' flag. You can reliably have four Host Instances banging data into SQL without fear of them tripping over each other.
2. At a scheduled time, have BizTalk extract all of the records that are marked as unprocessed in that SQL Table (the WCF-SQL Adapter can help you here). Once you have polled the records, mark them as 'in-process'.
3. You should now have a single message containing all of the currently unprocessed records (as retrieved from SQL). Using a single (or multiple) Host Instance/s, write the  message to disk, appending each of the records to the file in a single write. The key here is that you are only writing a *single message to the one file*, not lots and lots and lots :-)
4. If the write is successful, update each of the records in the SQL table with a 'processed' flag so they are not picked-up again on the next poll.

You might want to consider a singleton orchestration for this piece to ensure that there is only ever one poll-write-update process taking place at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If FIFO is important, BizTalk has ordered delivery mechanism (FILE adapter supported) but it comes at performance cost.

The better solution would be let instances writing to individual files and then have another scheduled process (or orchestration) to combine them in one file. You can enforce FIFO using timestamps. This would provide better performance and resource utilization vs. mentioned earlier singleton orchestration. Other option may be using any suitable implementation of a queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can move to a database system instead of a file. That would be very simply solution and also very efficient.
If you don't want to go that way, you must implement file locking or a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) inside of your application so the new threads will wait for other threads to finish writing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But sendport is using FileAdapter to write to that file. We can't use database. At EOD, that file gets backed up and ftp to another location. Using Sempaphore you mean to write custom adapter ?

Comment: That will most likely be required in order to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Puciek..I just wanted to confirm this... Do mean to say writing custom Adapter is the only option to acheive this? File Adapter doesn't by default lock text files.

Comment: I can't think of any other of the top of my head.